# Is there a way to maintain the serializer order?

Tags: python, django

If I write this order for `AddressRegionDetailSerializer` and `AvailableAreaSerializer`:

```
class AddressRegionDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    地域详情（包含可用区域）
    """
    availableareas = AvailableAreaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = AddressRegion
        fields = "__all__"

class AvailableAreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    可用地区
    """

    class Meta:
        model = AvailableArea
        fields = "__all__"
```

There will report NameError issue:

```
NameError: name 'AvailableAreaSerializer' is not defined
```

in this line:

```
availableareas = AvailableAreaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

So, I must put the `AvailableAreaSerializer` in the front. 
But however in my idea, I want to write the Serializer as the Models order, I don't want to break this law.

So, is there a simple way to maintain this order?

Comment: If you want to keep things tidy, you could put your models in `models.py` and your serializers in `serializers.py` and then import your models into `serializers.py`.

Comment: @Blurp Yes, I do like this, I means, I want to the serializers order as same as the models order in .py files.